# Can't run two scripts simultaneously in npm

Tags: npm, package.json, mern, react-fullstack

I'm trying to run two scripts in my fullstack app from root directory. Root directory has following structure:
./client
./server
./package.json (which is supposed to run both client and server). Client and server has their own package.json files where there is given scripts to run each.

In my root package.json I have following command:

```
"scripts": {
"server":"npm run dev --prefix server",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"watch": "npm run server & npm run client"
```

But only server is running. Can't run the client with this command

Comment: That command will run the server, wait for it to finish, then run the client, it won't launcho both together. If you need to programs running concurrently, open two consoles and run one script in each.

Comment: @Alejandro in the video tutorial where I was following instructor said if you got two ampersands then it'll wait for first one finish to start the second. But if there is only one ampersand both should work concurrently and it's running in the video I'm watching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem. The reason was running two scripts simultaneously with ampersand (&) does not work in windows shell. So I had to change my default shell to bash shell with `npm config set script-shell bash`